# Can a map be used as a tree?

Tags: c++, tree, c++17, stdmap

eg. `std::map<Item, std::vector<Item> >`.

Would that be able serve as a "quick-and-dirty" tree structure (with some helper functions on top and given that `less` is implemented for Item), given that theres none in the std/boost ?

Would a `std::unordered_map` be better suited/more usefull/beneficial ? that requires a hash instead of compare though - which can be harder to implement.

I can see one issue though, finding parent/owner have to brute force go through the entire map (although that might be best stored in seperate structure if needed).

Another thing Im *not* so fond of is the sort of dual meaning of a map entry with an Item with an empty child list.

Comment: Only if you understand that each value in the tree may occur twice, once as a value and once as the key. Using a `std::shared_ptr` on the other hand...

Comment: `std::vector` owns its data, so if each item inside a `std::vector` also appear as a key in the `std::map`, you will have several times the same objects (such a waste of memory IMHO).

Comment: @Fareanor depends on what item actually is I guess - sometimes ptr or shared_ptr isn't desired due to complexity or otherwise

Comment: I guess one could store a std::optional<Item> for parent lookup - or just a seperate structure.

Comment: Keys in a map are immutable, but values are not. So if you are using the `Item` instances in your `vector<Item>` as keys to get other items, you cannot really enforce this invariant properly (well, you can "cheat" with pointers)

Comment: @darune Agreed. If the `Item` is smaller than a pointer, it could make sense indeed.

Comment: @Fareanor another issue with pointers is that it's complicated to copy the entire or part of the structure or it's a shallow copy with eg. `shared_ptr`

Comment: @AndyG good point, that could be solved by making key parts const though (i think)

Comment: That looks more like a graph. All trees are graphs, but not all graphs are trees. Since you'll have to add the tree logic, I'd recommend just implementing a tree with nodes. (However if you just need the tree to do some particular task, you might be better off with one of the standard library containers.)

Comment: I am in favor of closing this question since it is very unspecific and possibly also very opinion based.

Comment: maybe you can use a vector<Item> for storage, and unordered_map<vector<Item>::const_iterator, vector<vector<Item>::const_iterator> to represent the tree (parent/child) relationship.

Comment: @SPD vector iterator gets easily invalidated

Comment: @darune I'm sure you know how to overcome that if deletion needs to be supported ;-) Seriously though, I think ideally you can achieve what you want by using a `unordered_map<Item, vector<iterator_of_this_container>>`, but I can't figure out how to make _iterator_of_this_container_ as value of this unordered_map. So I think you need two containers: one for storage, the other for tree relationship

Answer (score 1):

> Can a map be used as a tree?

Situation is inverse: `std::map` is internally implemented using a tree. So tree can (is) used as a map.

Neither map nor unordered map are useful for implementing a general tree structure. Only if your intention is to use the tree as a map would it be useful to use these structures (because they are maps which was desirable in this scenario)

Comment: I do not want to go into a deeper discussion here, but the tree in map is a binary (search) tree and is a highly specialized/cs technical tree - not exactly the same as a parent-child relationship tree or just a tree in generel (a heirachy tree for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely represent a tree in this manner; whether it's a good idea in a given situation depends entirely on which operations you need to be fast, which operations you're okay with being slow, and what your space requirements are.

(And of course in many applications the answer to all of the above may be "I don't care," in which case *any* implementation is probably fine.)